# Trusted type provider will not load

Tags: sql-server, f#, type-providers

I am trying to use the F# [`SqlDataConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362320.aspx) from a Visual Studio 2013 F# project.  I added a reference to the `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders` assembly using the "Add Reference" dialog.  When asked to trust the type provider I clicked "Enable" and when viewing the F# Tools options I can see that the dll is indeed trusted.

[image: Trusted type providers]

However, when trying to use the type provider, I am getting a warning saying that the dll is not trusted and will not be loaded and the `SqlDataConnection` is not recognized by the compiler:

[image]

What am I missing?

My code:

```ml
open System
open System.IO
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq

type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"SomeConnectionString">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the type provider assembly from the internet directly (e.g. as a ZIP file), then the type provider assembly may be "blocked" by Windows - you can right click on the DLL and click the "Unblock" button [as shown, for example, here](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2011/08/17/unblock-referenced-assemblies.aspx).

I also think that you may run into this issue when the assembly is located on a network mapped drive (i.e. if you had it somewhere on a server and had that location mapped as `Z:\`)

Comment: The assembly was installed with the VS2013 installation and is not blocked. It is located on my local C-drive. I have used the type provider before in .fsx files without any problems by copying the dll to the directory of the .fsx file.  But when referencing it in a F# project using the "Add Reference" dialog it is not working for me.

Comment: @JakobChristensen Hm, those were the usual suspects! Can you provide more details about the error message you're getting?

Comment: Yes, I know.  I am out of ideas.  I updated my question with a screenshot of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure FSharp.Data.TypeProviders is marked as 'Trusted'.**

1. Go to Tools>Options>F# Tools>Type Providers
2. Make sure "Trusted" is checked for FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

[image]